# Replace content while ignoring links and html tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm replacing the smiley shortcuts from my text editor with img tags, but the logic I use also sees parts of links and tags as smiley shortcuts (e.g. **:/** in **http://**, or **:p** in **cursor:pointer** in the style attribute)

How can I ignore all the links and html tags while replacing smiley shortcuts with images?

```
for(var key in shortcuts){
    // Check if the editor html contains the looped shortcut
    if(content.toLowerCase().indexOf(key) != -1){
        // Escaping special characters to be able to use the shortcuts in regular expression
        var k = key.replace(/[<>*()?']/g, "\\$&");

        // Make shortcuts case insensitive
        var regex = new RegExp(k, "ig");

        //Replace shortcuts with img tags (smileys)
        tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(content.replace(regex,'<img src="images/transparent.png" class="smiley_icon '+ shortcuts[key] +'">'));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is way too complex. the solution is to configure/re-program your text-editor to insert the smileys the way you want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Description

I think the way I'd approach this is to match everything bad along with everything good. Then in the expression only put into the capture group the text glyphs I was interested in. Later in the programming logic I'd test each match to see if capture group 1 was populated, if so then the match`.index` will show where in the string that match occurred.

This expression will find all the `:/`, `:)`, `:p`, tags and urls, but capture group 1 will only contain the `:)`, `:/`, or `:p` which are not part of a tag or url.

`https?:\/\/[^\s]*|<\/?\w+\b(?=\s|>)(?:='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*|[^>])*>|(:\)|:P|:\/)`

[image]

## Expanded

- `https?:\/\/[^\s]*` matches a url in plain text
- `|` or
- `<\/?\w+\b(?=\s|>)(?:='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*|[^>])*>` matches any open or close html tags
- `|` or
- `(:\)|:P|:\/)` capture group 1 will get the desired text glyphs

## Example:

Live example: http://regexr.com?35cv9 (Hover over the blue matches to see each of of the capture groups and index)

**Sample Text**

```
<a href=http://i.like.kittens style="cursor:point"> :) I had a :/ great time :p </a> check out http://some.url.com
```

**matches**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <a href=http://i.like.kittens style="cursor:point">
        [1] => :)
        [2] => :/
        [3] => :p
        [4] => </a>
        [5] => http://some.url.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => :)
        [2] => :/
        [3] => :p
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
    )
```